# Adding css classes to TinyMce elements within Moodle

Tags: css, tinymce, moodle

I have an instance of moodle running and I need to add specific classes to elements generated by tinyMce when the user clicks a button on the tinymce interface. So for example the user highlights some text clicks the list button and behind the scenes in the markup tinymce adds a class to the ul that is generated in the editor.

This would be a rather straight forward process ([described here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.addClass)) but as with everything moodle, tinymce has been heavily integrated into it. There is very little documentation on the moodle site about how to configure TinyMce (which is not helpful moodle). The forums dont have much info specific to what I am after either so if anyone could guide/point me in the right direction here it would be great.

Comment: Is it just getting TinyMce config into Moodle that's the issue? If so, the TinyMce code is stored at lib/editor/tinymce/tiny_mce/ and all the configuration is in the get_init_params function in lib/editor/tinymce/lib.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no plugin or configuration for this. Looks like you will have to develop your own plugin with this functionality (which shouldn't be that difficult).